# dispatch_after is limited to 10 seconds?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, background, grand-central-dispatch

I'm developing an app which is running in background. Sometimes I need to tell the user that something is happenning so I play a sound a certain number of times. To do that I made a timer but the problem is that It cannot exceed 10s of the total delayed time, after that, there are no more sounds (but the app is still running). I've checked this behavior in foreground mode and it works perfectly.

This is my code when I need to inform the user:

```
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(alarma);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
    numAlarm = 1;  
    NSTimeInterval delay_in_seconds = 2.0;
    dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delay_in_seconds*NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
    dispatch_after(delay,queue,^{
        [self fiBGTemps:ALARM];
    });
```

and the "fiBGTemps" is something like this,

```
- (void)fiBGTemps:(int)sender
{
    switch (sender){
        case TEMP_SCAN:
            (…)
            break;
        case ALARM:
            if (numAlarm>0 && numAlarm<NUM_ALARM)
            {
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(alarma);
                AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
                NSTimeInterval delay_in_seconds = 2;
                dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delay_in_seconds*NSEC_PER_SEC);
                dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);
                dispatch_after(delay,queue,^{
                    [self fiBGTemps:ALARM];
                });
                numAlarm++;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Is that behavior normal? Am I missing something?

Thanks

Kanick

Comment: What is NUM_ALARM set to? Maybe that's whats limiting the number of loops. Besides, it seems here that you have a sequence of two second delays not a ten second delay.

Comment: Hi @aLevelOfIndirection, NUM_ALARM is a constant that I set to test that time limit (#define NUM_ALARM 20). In this way I can see how many times the sound sounds. Another way I tested is changing the "delay_in_seconds" value. If I set this value to 8 (for example) it plays only 2 sounds. If I set this value to 12 (more than 10) it plays only one sound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

This is what happens. When an app is running in background and and it is executed a task, this task is running in background as well but the system allows only a certain amount of time (10s apron.) in order to safe battery. So it is only for a specific tasks (localization, download, etc.).

I my case I need a little more time so the solution is to define the task as a UIBackgroundTask in such a way that will be the task who notify the system when it is completed and thus can be terminated.

this is the code where it is called the task:

```
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    __block UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier background_task;
    background_task = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: ^{
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self fiBGTemps:@(ALARM)];
        [application endBackgroundTask: background_task];
        background_task = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    });
```

And here you can see the discussion on the Apple Forums where they explain this better than me.

[AppleForums discussion](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/185374?tstart=0)

I hope this helps.

Kanick

Comment: Where will you add delay?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with re-setting the delay value after it exceed 10s of the total delayed time or may be after it has played sound for certain amount of time.

Comment: Yes, indeed thats what I've done. I've set the delay at 2 seconds and (for testing) this is repeated more than 5 times (>10 seconds). Once it is reached that 10s time there is no more response (it seems like an infinite time). So I can't do it again.

Comment: Can u please share the sample value that will be passed to dispatch_after

  dispatch_after(delay,queue,^{
        [self fiBGTemps:ALARM];
    });

Need to know what these variables (delay and queue)stores...

dispatch_time_t delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,delay_in_seconds*NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0);

Comment: Hi, @ManikantThakur, This is what is passed to the dispatch_after: delay_in_seconds = 8(with this value it plays only one sound), NSEC_PER_SEC is a constant declared in clock_types.h (#define NSEC_PER_SEC 1000000000ull), the queue is the same I shown in the code above, and NUM_ALARM is 15 (this values doesn't really matter, the important thing is NUM_ALARM*delay_in_seconds > 10s in order to see the effect). Is that what are you asking for?

Comment: Well, will passing 8 every time in delay_in_seconds work for u??If yes, u can keep is constant.

Because passing 8 in delay_in_seconds is working for you,as you said.
And if u go with this, then as per ur example it will greater then 10s

NUM_ALARM*delay_in_seconds > 10s
15 * 8 = 120.

And as per ur first response, if it reaches 10s time, it doesnt respond. So try with resetting the value of delay/repeat_time back to default value. Also keep a constant check so that it doesn't crosses 10.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not so clear in may last comment. That 8 seconds are not good for me it doesn't work. I said 8 in order to reproduce, to force the problem, to see what is happening. I need to control delays beyond that 10s (not minutes, but something more than 10). Now the limit is NUM_ALARM*delay_in_seconds = 10 and I don't know why.

Comment: what will the value/output of delay_in_seconds*NSEC_PER_SEC ??

Comment: Acording to the documentation, the second parameter of dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t when,int64_t delta) is the time value in nanoseconds, that's why have to be XX*NSEC_PER_SEC.

Comment: I think the correct format is 

dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2LL * NSEC_PER_SEC);

for 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that chaining asynch blocks to play sounds at regular intervals is a bit of an overkill. Perhaps something simpler along the following lines would be easier to understand and maintain:

```
// To initiate the alarm:
[self fiBGTemps: ALARM];

- (void)fiBGTemps:(int)sender
{
    switch (sender) {
       ...
       case ALARM:
           dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
                int count = 0;
                while (count < NUM_ALARM /* AND not interrupted by user? */) {
                    sleep(2);
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(alarma);
                    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
                    count++;
                }
            });
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @aLevelOfIndirection. I've just tried your approach and I observed the same results. May be the problem is not on the code (cleaner or not in foreground works well). May be there is some configuration parameter or something like that.

Comment: How long (in seconds) are the sound files for alarms?