# dispatch_after and [UIView animation: duration] happen immediately (but shouldn't)

Tags: ios, uiview, ios7, grand-central-dispatch

With iOS7,  we are getting an intermittent bug. It didn't happen with iOS6.

It doesn't start right away, but ~30sec to ~2 min into the game, ALL of the animations, and the dispatch_after commands happen instantaneously.

To be more specific, the animations are happening as if the "duration:" value is 0, even though it is definitely not 0.
To be more specific, the dispatch_after is happening as if the wait = 0.

Once it starts, it persists until the software is terminated.

I have no idea how to debug this, or if it is an iOS7 bug.  Any thoughs/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should show some code

Comment: I have the same problem.  It seems to only happen after about 5 minutes of gameplay, and so far I can only reproduce it on an iPad2 running iOS7.    It usually seems to happen when the RAM for the app hits 80MB (out of 256 that the iPad2 has).  This initially struck me as a ton of memory being used. It seems like all the images I used are being cached in memory (even if they are no longer on screen and no references are being held to them - eg no memory leak).  I'm going to try to reduce the memory footprint of the app and see if that helps.

Comment: I have a grid of views and a gesture fires off an animation that changes the background color of each view, with the animations spaced apart by a constant. After ~30 iterations, the animations start to happen at the same time. First, two animations will fire at once, then a few animations later, 3 will fire at once, and so on. BUT! If the gesture fires another round, a new set of animations begin executing AND the previous animations that haven't fired yet start to behave again.

Comment: I wonder if this is some sort of optimization that wasn't thought through, or a bottleneck of GCD scheduling. Are you using Core Animation APIs or UIView animation APIs? I'm using UIView and GCD.

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295953/dispatch-after-is-limited-to-10-seconds

Comment: A nasty but workable solution (in my case at least) is setting a repeating NSTimer that calls a method which creates an otherwise meaningless GCD scheduled task. It throws the scheduler back into order for at least a small while.

Answer (score 1):

Is the problem that you believe your completion block is being called prematurely?

If so, have you checked the value of the Boolean value passed into the completion block? You may want to only execute the statements in that block if the Boolean value is true.

e.g.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration... animations:^{
    //do something
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        // do something
    }
}];
```

I saw this when the completion block was being called before the animation had even started, but it was actually because something else had cancelled the animation, hence `finished = NO`.

This doesn't answer the question regarding `dispatch_after`, so you may still be experiencing a bug there.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem as outlined in the question above, and even when animateWithDuration runs immediately, finished is still YES

Answer (score 0):

The Question title and the descriptions seems to be a differ(unClear to understand), anyhow if you want to to produce the task after sometime then look at below

> dispatch_after and [UIView animation: duration] happen immediately

This could work :

```
// Do your stuff OR animations then use below for DISPATCH_AFTER...
 double delayInSeconds = 2.0f;
            dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                // Do your Stuff Or Add Animation
                [UIView animateWithDuration:.6f animations:^{
                    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 173);

                }];
            });
```

Comment: I think the questioner has already implemented the GCD scheduling of the animations. That is not the problem. The problem is that after a certain amount of time, GCD seems to ignore the spacing between the tasks in it's queue- just firing off the rest of the scheduled tasks immediately, or in a lump.

Answer (score 0):

Your question sounds like you're not calling the animations and dispatches on the **main thread**. This causes unexpected behaviour, such as views not updating or moving until a certain point in time.

Please try to move the animation block inside a dispatch_main like so:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <# Code #>
});
```

and see if it fixes the problem.

Comment: I am calling all scheduled operations on the main thread. I don't think the animations would behave initially if this wasn't the case.